# Can an LLM with functions be used to solve a toy geometry problem?

Tags: langchain, chatgpt-api, large-language-model

I have constructed a toy problem that I would like to solve using an LLM like ChatGPT (and likely functions, langchain or something similar).

I have four locations (each location is a rectangle and has `name`) as JSON.

Then I have 3 "scenes", each scene is also a JSON file. Each scene has a number of colored polygons that are each inside one of the locations and a `date` field. Here are the three scenes with the locations plotted as the black rectangles.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[locations.json](https://gist.github.com/nickponline/b0e0d5f55493b1c0731ca1bef0960ca1)

[scene1.json](https://gist.github.com/nickponline/aa23fe2156d927e6087673e8f034e7f3)

[scene2.json](https://gist.github.com/nickponline/e1a05ad6cbdb8d9a14266ed50e8c2740)

[scene3.json](https://gist.github.com/nickponline/5bf99928ff1d2719a0f9450faaa9dbf2)

I would like to task an LLM with creating two tables as output given these 3 `scenes` and `locations` JSON as input.

The first table should be the total area of each colored shape per scene, for example:

```
1 January 2 January 3 January
Red 105.09,  102.71, 93.67 
Green 24.25, 58.96, 29.95
Blue 41.37, 62.76, 64.19
```

The second table should be the area of each shape in each location.

```
January 1 January 2 January 3
Location A 50.88 38.51 29.95
Location B 24.25 58.96 29.95
Location C 41.37 62.76 64.19
Location D 54.21 64.19 63.72
```

Assume the existence of two functions that are needed to solve this problem. One for determining if a location contains a shape `def contains(shape1, shape2)` and another for determining the area of a shape `def get_area(shape)`.

I'd like the LLM to make the requisite calls to these two functions and then create the two tables as output? Is this possible and how should this be structured.

PS: My code for generating and solving this problem (without LLM) is [here](https://gist.github.com/nickponline/b71bb7458f964d15c732e3a4df0ce2ac)

Comment: You can try something similar to PAL. Create a prompt with an example and steps to reach the solution. 
For this you can do something like locatoin are defined as ..., scenes are defined as ...
Now to find the area you do `mention` manual steps, and try. If LLM you're working on is finetuned on this type of data this will give model some insight on how to approach this. This is interesting I'll give it a try sometime on weeknd. 
For step by step process you can give description to chatGPT and it should be able to suggest the prompt itself.